# How can I properly run ajax on my node server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express

I want to call an ajax function on a form that uploads new products to the database.
Even though I disable the event's default behaviour in my script.js, the page still refreshes because of the router.post() method.

my index.js (backend):

```
router.post('/dashboard', (req, res) => {

    const{name, pricePerUnit, productDescription, productAmmount} = req.body;
    let errors = [];
    console.log(global.useremail);

    //Check required fields
    if(!name || !pricePerUnit || !productDescription || !productAmmount){
        errors.push({msg : "Enter all fields"});
    }

    if(errors.length > 0){
        res.render('dashboard', {
            name,
            pricePerUnit,
            productDescription,
            productAmmount,
            errors,
        });
    }else{
        //Add record
    }
});
```

my script.js (front-end):

```
$(document).ready(()=>{

$('#submitNewProduct').submit((e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();

    const data = getFormDataAsJSON($('newproduct-form'));

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/dashboard',
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json'
    });
});
```

});

Comment: I think it is because of you render `view` in node. you might only need to do `res.send({"your json"})` or `res.json("your json")`

Comment: Side note - This looks wrong: `$('newproduct-form')`

Comment: *"Even though I disable the event's default behaviour in my script.js, the page still refreshes because of the router.post() method."* No, that' s not why. The response can't reach out and change what the page does with it. If the page is refreshing, it's because the form submission is not being prevented. Step through the client-side code to see why that is.

Comment: If I do res.send({'my jason'}) the page will output a json file, it will not update the same page.

Comment: The only lines of code that alter the form on the front end (and backend) is the ones i posted. So I believe that even though I'm trying to prevent a refresh on the client side, the server side still pushes to refresh no?

Comment: Are you sure the client side code you posted is after the jquery import? Else this wont run at all and will throw error.

Answer (score 0):

Edit : I think if you use `.on("click", ...)` instead of `.submit(...)` it can solve your problem

```
$('#submitNewProduct').on("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
```

---

You are using the `relative path` like if you were always on your node app, but you are not because the front end app is execute on client side.

You have to call the entire `url` of your server node like :

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/dashboard',
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

On my example your server is running on `localhost` on port `8080`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried this and the page still reloads itself.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using ajax in frontend side then your server must return response in JSON .

**res.render** will render a page from server side ,every time you submit a form .
 so you must use **res.json()**

```
if(errors.length > 0){
     res.json({status:"error",errors:errors});
}else{
    //Add record
     res.json({status:"success",record:record});
}
```